# How to create, read, append and delete a file in Cordova 5.0

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am working with Cordova 5.0 with android platform, i want to create, read, append and delete files in my app. I have read some posts about cordova file system but they are out of date. Can you please provide a simple example to do this.

Comment: Have you written any code for it after reading the posts?

Comment: yes, here is the link to docs which i have used http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_file_file.md.html

Comment: Here you find a lot of informations: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.file

Comment: I already used that information, but it did not worked for me.